# is it possible to find out if a ruby socket is in state ESTABLISHED or CLOSE_WAIT without actually sending or reading data?

Tags: ruby, sockets, select, openssl

```
s = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)
s.connect(Socket.pack_sockaddr_in('port', 'hostname'))

ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(s, sslcert)
ssl.connect
```

From here on I would like to check in a thread if the ssl connection and the underlying socket is still `ESTABLISHED` or if it went into `CLOSE_WAIT` after the default of 7200 seconds or even worse got closed without actually needing to `.write()` to or `.read()` from it.

Is it done with`select()`, `IO.select()` or another method?

BTW: The socket never receives any data it just sends some occasionally.

Answer (score 12):

The answer is [implementation specific](http://www.developerweb.net/forum/showthread.php?t=4395).  You'll need to check tcp implementation header files on your OS.  Here is a sample client for linux that returns the socket state.

```
  ts = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5777)
  ssl = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(ts, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new)
  ssl.sync = true
  ssl.connect
  # TCP_INFO is 11
  # note that TCP_INFO isn't defined in the ruby source.  
  # i had to look up the integer value in /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h
  optval = ts.getsockopt(Socket::SOL_TCP, 11) 
  state = optval.unpack "i" 
  puts "state: #{state}"
```

Here's the tcp_info struct for my up-to-date ubuntu linux

```
struct tcp_info
{
  u_int8_t      tcpi_state;
  u_int8_t      tcpi_ca_state;
  u_int8_t      tcpi_retransmits;
  u_int8_t      tcpi_probes;
  u_int8_t      tcpi_backoff;
  u_int8_t      tcpi_options;
  u_int8_t      tcpi_snd_wscale : 4, tcpi_rcv_wscale : 4;

  u_int32_t     tcpi_rto;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_ato;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_snd_mss;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_rcv_mss;

  u_int32_t     tcpi_unacked;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_sacked;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_lost;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_retrans;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_fackets;

  /* Times. */
  u_int32_t     tcpi_last_data_sent;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_last_ack_sent;     /* Not remembered, sorry.  */
  u_int32_t     tcpi_last_data_recv;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_last_ack_recv;

  /* Metrics. */
  u_int32_t     tcpi_pmtu;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_rcv_ssthresh;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_rtt;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_rttvar;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_snd_ssthresh;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_snd_cwnd;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_advmss;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_reordering;

  u_int32_t     tcpi_rcv_rtt;
  u_int32_t     tcpi_rcv_space;

  u_int32_t     tcpi_total_retrans;
};
```

You may note that my script only returns an integer.  Here's the C enum that details the TCP states and their integer values.  Again, this was found in /usr/include/netinet/tcp.h

```
enum
{   
  TCP_ESTABLISHED = 1,          
  TCP_SYN_SENT,
  TCP_SYN_RECV,
  TCP_FIN_WAIT1,
  TCP_FIN_WAIT2,
  TCP_TIME_WAIT,
  TCP_CLOSE,
  TCP_CLOSE_WAIT,
  TCP_LAST_ACK,
  TCP_LISTEN, 
  TCP_CLOSING   /* now a valid state */
};
```

Also, this [thread](http://fixunix.com/tcp-ip/66328-detecting-socket-state.html) says that you can detect CLOSE_WAIT by reading EOF.  But since you're concerned about whether data has been sent, you'll probably need to unpack up to tcpi_last_data_sent.

Finally, a caveat.  I took on the challenge of answering your question 'cause it sounded fun and it was but my C legs are still wobbly so YMMV. :)